# MySql 8.0 - Filtered JSON query

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-json

I have a JSON blob that I am trying to extract a value from, specifically, the Zip Code under the Rating Information section (Expected value = 90703).  Does MySql 8 support JSON filter expressions?

JSON:

> ```
> {
>   "quote_number": null,
>   "items": [
>       {
>           "annual_amount": 0.0,
>           "pro_rata_amount": 0.0,
>           "name": "Value Information",
>           "categories": {
>               "Use": "Single Family Detached",
>               "Zip Code": "51431",
>               "Floor Coverings": "Carpet"
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           "annual_amount": 0.0,
>           "pro_rata_amount": 0.0,
>           "name": "Rating Information",
>           "categories": {
>               "Number of Non-Weather Water Losses": "0",
>               "Protection Class": "2",
>               "Zip Code": "90703",
>               "Special Hazard Interface Area": "N"
>           }
>       }
>   ],
>   "total": {
>       "annual_fees": 0.0,
>       "annual_premium": 9.0
>   },
>   "policy_id": null
> }
> ```

Path: $.items[?(@.name=="Rating Information")].categories.Zip Code

The path appears to be correct as I get data when testing via this site: https://jsonpath.com/

If MySql doesn't support JSON filtering, what is the recommended work around?

Joe

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it supports filtering. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths MySQL JSON path syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 and 8.1 does not implement full support for jsonpath expressions. For example, it does not support filtering expressions. The limited support for jsonpath is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax

The solution in MySQL for filtering JSON data is to use `JSON_TABLE()`.

I tested your data:

```
set @j = '{ ...your json... }';

select * from json_table(@j, '$.items[*]' columns(
name text path '$.name',
zip_code text path '$.categories."Zip Code"'
)) as j;

+--------------------+----------+
| name               | zip_code |
+--------------------+----------+
| Value Information  | 51431    |
| Rating Information | 90703    |
+--------------------+----------+
```

You can then put a WHERE clause on the query to get the one you want.

Read more about JSON_TABLE(): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html