# MySQL JSON - How to extract a "value" for a particular "Key" from an array of Named Key/Value Pairs

Tags: mysql, arrays, key-value, mysql-json

Given a JSON path that contains an array of Named Key/Value pairs, how to extract the "Value" for the "Name" pair:

```
# JSON_PRETTY(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Tags'))
[
    {
        "Key" : "Environment",
        "Value" : "Production"
    },
    {
        "Key" : "Description",
        "Value" : "Production Message Broker"
    },
    {
        "Key" : "Version",
        "Value" : "1"
    },
    {
        "Key" : "Application Role",
        "Value" : "Message Broker"
    },
    {
        "Key" : "Reserved Instance",
        "Value" : "Y - 3 year"
    },
    {
        "Key" : "Patch Group",
        "Value" : "Saturday9am"
    },
    {
        "Key" : "Name",
        "Value" : "mb023323"
    }
]
```

IE, how do I get the "Name" "Value"?  "mb023323" in this example?

I've reviewed numerous articles and books, but can find no query that addresses what I need.  (Of course, I may just not understand how to specify a JSON path correctly.)

Comment: Your json structire is unnecessarily complicated as it basically stores data in key - value pairs. What you did here is not a key - value pair but you need to find a json object with key property set to name  and retrieve its value property's value.

Comment: Well maybe you could share what you already tried so we can find the error in your approach. Or you could read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680515/find-object-in-nested-data-by-property-value-with-jsonpath  which addresses a very similar problem (not in the context of MySQL though) but I assume that MySQL will unterstand JSON path nonetheless

Comment: @derpirscher MySQL has limited support for JSON path, so it won't help in this case. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66803992/20860

Comment: Thanks for all your responses.  I agree with @Shadow, it is complicated, but it's how it is delivered to us.  And Bill, I'm going to assume your response is the answer, MySQL just doesn't support this level of parsing.  Thanks, again.